# How to repair Corrupted Mp4 file generated by MediaMuxer?

Tags: android, mp4, h.264, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I used `MediaMuxer` and `MediaCodec` to generate a mp4 video.

The video is playble after I call `mMediaMuxer.stop()`

However, when the user quit the app before I get the change to call the `stop()` method, I am left with a big mp4 file that is not playable.

Is there anyway to repair this mp4 file to make it playable?

## Edit

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CscSdGSYjKFyQPWWqbLjSp3-MmXNa7lc/view?usp=sharing) is one example of a corrupted mp4 file

And I was able to repair the file using [this online tool](https://fix.video/fix-video.php)  but this tool asked to upload a non-corrupted video as reference.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xoIYUUV3SLpmAX7Yojt7ofPd4ha4aSp_/view?usp=sharing) is the non-corrupted mp4 video that I used as reference. When I uploaded this video, the tool repaired my broken mp4 file.

So it is possible to repair the file but how did they do it?

If useful, here is the code I used to generate both corrupted and non corrupted

```
package com.tolotra.images_to_video

import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.media.*
import android.opengl.*
import android.util.Log
import android.util.TimingLogger
import android.view.Surface
import java.io.File
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder
import java.nio.FloatBuffer
import java.nio.IntBuffer
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*


class VideoBuilder(applicationContext: Context) {


    private var frameId: Long = 0
    private lateinit var muxer: MediaMuxer
    private lateinit var glTool: OverlayRenderer
    private lateinit var encoder: MediaCodec
    private lateinit var outVideoFilePath: String
    private var context = applicationContext
    private var trackIndex: Int = 0
    private lateinit var bufferInfo: MediaCodec.BufferInfo
    private var eglContext: EGLContext? = null
    private var eglDisplay: EGLDisplay? = null
    private var eglSurface: EGLSurface? = null
    private lateinit var surface: Surface


    val timeoutUs = 10000L
    val frameRate = 5
    var presentationTimeUs: Long = 0


    fun setup() {
        encoder = createEncoder()
        initInputSurface(encoder)
        encoder.start()

        outVideoFilePath = getScreenshotPath("tolotra-screen-recoder-${Date().time}.mp4")
        muxer = MediaMuxer(outVideoFilePath, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)

        glTool = OverlayRenderer()
        glTool.initGl()
    }

    /**
     * Laspse is the duration between the current frame and the previous frame
     */
    fun feed(bitmap: Bitmap, timelapse: Long) {

        frameId++
        Log.d("FEED_PROFILE", "feed frame:$frameId")
        val timings = TimingLogger("FEED_PROFILE", "feed frame:$frameId")
        // Get encoded data and feed it to muxer
        drainEncoder(encoder, muxer, false, timelapse)

        timings.addSplit("drainEncoder done");
        // Render the bitmap/texture with OpenGL here
        glTool.render(bitmap)
        timings.addSplit("render done");

        // Set timestamp with EGL extension
        EGLExt.eglPresentationTimeANDROID(eglDisplay, eglSurface, presentationTimeUs * 1000)

        // Feed encoder with next frame produced by OpenGL
        EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface)

        timings.dumpToLog();
    }

    fun finish() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Finishing")

        // Drain last encoded data and finalize the video file
        drainEncoder(encoder, muxer, true, 0)
        _cleanUp(encoder, muxer)

        val file = File(outVideoFilePath)

        val file_size = (file.length() / 1024).toString().toInt()
        val retriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
        retriever.setDataSource(outVideoFilePath)
        val width =
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH)
        val height =
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT)
        val rotation =
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION)

        val bitRate =
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_BITRATE)

        val duration =
            java.lang.Long.valueOf(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION)) * 1000

        Log.d("Result", "bitrate $bitRate duration $duration  fileSize $file_size ")

    }

    fun getScreenshotPath(fileName: String): String {
        val f = context.externalCacheDir
        val externalDir: String = f!!.path;
        val sDir: String = externalDir + File.separator + "Screen Recorder";
        val dir = File(sDir);
        val dirPath: String;
        if (dir.exists() || dir.mkdir()) {
            dirPath = sDir + File.separator + fileName;
        } else {
            dirPath = externalDir + File.separator + fileName
        }
        Log.d("Mp4 file path", "Path: $dirPath")

        return dirPath;
    } //


    fun createEncoder(): MediaCodec {

        bufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
        val MIME = "video/avc"
        val encoder = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIME)
        val width = 320
        val heigh = 512
        val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME, width, heigh)
        format.setInteger(
            MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface
        )
//        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 2_000_000)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 350_000)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 45)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5)

        encoder.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
        trackIndex = -1;
        return encoder
    }

    fun drainEncoder(
        encoder: MediaCodec,
        muxer: MediaMuxer,
        endOfStream: Boolean,
        timelapseUs: Long
    ) {
        if (endOfStream)
            encoder.signalEndOfInputStream()

        while (true) {
            val outBufferId = encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, timeoutUs)

            if (outBufferId >= 0) {
                val encodedBuffer = encoder.getOutputBuffer(outBufferId)

                // MediaMuxer is ignoring KEY_FRAMERATE, so I set it manually here
                // to achieve the desired frame rate
                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = presentationTimeUs
                if (encodedBuffer != null) {
                    muxer.writeSampleData(trackIndex, encodedBuffer, bufferInfo)
                }

                presentationTimeUs += timelapseUs

                encoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outBufferId, false)

                // Are we finished here?
                if ((bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0)
                    break
            } else if (outBufferId == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                if (!endOfStream)
                    break

                // End of stream, but still no output available. Try again.
            } else if (outBufferId == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                trackIndex = muxer.addTrack(encoder.outputFormat)
                muxer.start()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initInputSurface(encoder: MediaCodec) {

        val surface = encoder.createInputSurface()

        val eglDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
        if (eglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
            throw RuntimeException(
                "eglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY: "
                        + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError())
            )

        val version = IntArray(2)
        if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version, 0, version, 1))
            throw RuntimeException("eglInitialize(): " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))

        val attribList = intArrayOf(
            EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
            EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
            EGLExt.EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
        )
        val configs = arrayOfNulls<EGLConfig>(1)
        val nConfigs = IntArray(1)
        EGL14.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, attribList, 0, configs, 0, configs.size, nConfigs, 0)

        var err = EGL14.eglGetError()
        if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS)
            throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))

        val ctxAttribs = intArrayOf(
            EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
        )
        val eglContext =
            EGL14.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, configs[0], EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ctxAttribs, 0)

        err = EGL14.eglGetError()
        if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS)
            throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))

        val surfaceAttribs = intArrayOf(
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
        )
        val eglSurface =
            EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, configs[0], surface, surfaceAttribs, 0)
        err = EGL14.eglGetError()
        if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS)
            throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))

        if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext))
            throw RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent(): " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))


        this.eglSurface = eglSurface
        this.eglDisplay = eglDisplay
        this.eglContext = eglContext
        this.surface = surface
    }

    private fun _cleanUp(encoder: MediaCodec, muxer: MediaMuxer) {
        if (eglDisplay != EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            EGL14.eglDestroySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface)
            EGL14.eglDestroyContext(eglDisplay, eglContext)
            EGL14.eglReleaseThread()
            EGL14.eglTerminate(eglDisplay);
        }
        surface?.release();
        eglDisplay = EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY
        eglContext = EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT
        eglSurface = EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE

        encoder.stop()
        encoder.release()

        muxer.stop()
        muxer.release()
    }


}

class OverlayRenderer() {

    private val mvpMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private val projectionMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private val viewMatrix = FloatArray(16)

    private val vertexShaderCode =
        "precision highp float;\n" +
                "attribute vec3 vertexPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec2 uvs;\n" +
                "varying vec2 varUvs;\n" +
                "uniform mat4 mvp;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main()\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "\tvarUvs = uvs;\n" +
                "\tgl_Position = mvp * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);\n" +
                "}"

    private val fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "varying vec2 varUvs;\n" +
                "uniform sampler2D texSampler;\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void main()\n" +
                "{\t\n" +
                "\tgl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler, varUvs);\n" +
                "}"

    private var vertices = floatArrayOf(
        // x, y, z, u, v
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0f, 1f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1f, 1f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1f, 0f
    )

    private var indices = intArrayOf(
        2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2
    )

    private var program: Int = 0
    private var vertexHandle: Int = 0
    private var bufferHandles = IntArray(2)
    private var uvsHandle: Int = 0
    private var mvpHandle: Int = 0
    private var samplerHandle: Int = 0
    private val textureHandle = IntArray(1)


    val viewportWidth = 320
    val viewportHeight = 486


    var vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.size * 4).run {
        order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        asFloatBuffer().apply {
            put(vertices)
            position(0)
        }
    }

    var indexBuffer: IntBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.size * 4).run {
        order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
        asIntBuffer().apply {
            put(indices)
            position(0)
        }
    }

    fun render(bitmap: Bitmap) {

        Log.d("Bitmap", "width ${bitmap.width} height ${bitmap.height}")


// Prepare some transformations
        val mvp = FloatArray(16)
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mvp, 0)
        Matrix.scaleM(mvp, 0, 1f, -1f, 1f)

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        GLES20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)

        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, viewportWidth, viewportHeight)

        GLES20.glUseProgram(program)

// Pass transformations to shader
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpHandle, 1, false, mvp, 0)

// Prepare texture for drawing
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0)
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0])
        GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)

// Pass the Bitmap to OpenGL here
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0)

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST
        )
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST
        )

// Prepare buffers with vertices and indices & draw
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[0])
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[1])

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle)
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 5, 0)

        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvsHandle)
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(uvsHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 5, 3 * 4)

        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
    }


    fun initGl() {
        val vertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER).also { shader ->
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, vertexShaderCode)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
        }

        val fragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER).also { shader ->
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, fragmentShaderCode)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
        }

        program = GLES20.glCreateProgram().also {
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, vertexShader)
            GLES20.glAttachShader(it, fragmentShader)
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(it)

            vertexHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(it, "vertexPosition")
            uvsHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(it, "uvs")
            mvpHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(it, "mvp")
            samplerHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(it, "texSampler")
        }

        // Initialize buffers
        GLES20.glGenBuffers(2, bufferHandles, 0)

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[0])
        GLES20.glBufferData(
            GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            vertices.size * 4,
            vertexBuffer,
            GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW
        )

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferHandles[1])
        GLES20.glBufferData(
            GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
            indices.size * 4,
            indexBuffer,
            GLES20.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW
        )

        // Init texture handle
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0)

        // Ensure I can draw transparent stuff that overlaps properly
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND)
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can post a link to one of these Corrupted mp4 if needed

Comment: I'll take a link to your file.

Comment: I did post the corrupted video. Please check my question update. I also posted a non-corrupted video as a reference and the code I used to generate both files. – 
Also, it seems possible to repair using the online tool I referred to in my edit but how did they do it?

Comment: your question saved my day! In my case I mediaMuxer.stop call was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general MP4 is not a good recording format. Usually the sample table is kept in memory and written on close. So in case of a power loss or an application bug - you loose the recording. Use a MPEG-2 Transport Stream or a fragmented MP4 then most of the written media remains playable. Most likely your file will contains just a MP4 'ftyp' and 'mdat' atom with the audio and video interleaved. With some educated guessing and knowledge about the video stream - there is chance to extract audio and video. https://fix.video seems to do it.

```
Correct MP4:
[ftyp]
[mdat]
[moov]
-end-

Truncated MP4:
[ftyp]
[mdat]
-end-
```

Fix.video parses your good file extracts the settings for audio and video.
It uses the information from the good file to recreate most of the 'moov' atom. The missing sample tables 'stXX' are recreated by parsing your 'mdat' atom. The video chunks inside the 'mdat' atom are each prefixed with the length and the rest must be AAC audio.

Comment: I did post the corrupted video. Please check my question update. I also posted a non corrupted video as reference and the code I used to generate both files.

Comment: Also, it seems possible to repair using the online tool I referred to in my edit but how did they do it?

Comment: Thank you for the info, it's so hard to find user friendly info about this topic on the internet. Thanks for taking time to share your knowledge.

Comment: Thank you very much for your appreciation!